# Prevent output when creating an object from DLL assembly

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I'm loading a DLL and initializing new object and every time I create a new object, or use ReloadAll() method, I get output on the screen with the dump of the object contents. The object is initialized and works correctly, but I need to hide the output.

This is a behavior specific for this version of the DLL (v1.1.1)
Older version (v1.1.0) didn't have the issue, but it has a different bug... Anyway, code sample:

```
Add-Type -Path .\MSIAfterburner.NET.dll
$abMonitor = New-Object MSI.Afterburner.HardwareMonitor
$abMonitor.ReloadAll()
```

The question is how do I prevent the output?
I have tried:

```
$abMonitor = New-Object MSI.Afterburner.HardwareMonitor | Out-Null
$null = ($abMonitor = New-Object MSI.Afterburner.HardwareMonitor)
$abMonitor = New-Object MSI.Afterburner.HardwareMonitor *>$null
$abMonitor = New-Object MSI.Afterburner.HardwareMonitor >$null 2>&1
```

Comment: My guess is that you'll need to contact the assembly's author.  Essentially all of those should not be returning any output.  That suggests to me that the output is coming from one of the underlying libraries or the kernel itself and the assembly isn't handling it correctly.

Comment: Did send a message to the author, but he seems inactive, therefore I started searching for non obvious solutions :)